# Gerrit send underscore to Uploading Changes message

Tags: gerrit

we're using gerrit 2.14, I'm trying to send a message with my push to trigger jenkins.
problem is that I need to write bla_bla, but when I do:

```
git push ssh://link.to.repo/my_repo HEAD:refs/for/master%message=bla_bla
```

the message is "bla bla"
I've tried percent encoding, but then the message is "bla%f5bla"

Any ideas? old gerrit version? something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira mentioned, it seems it's not supported Gerrit 2.14

ElpiKay workaround is good:

ssh -p 29418 $username@$gerrithost gerrit review $commit -m "bla_bla"

Answer (score 0):

In Gerrit 2.15.x or superior the following command works:

```
git push ssh://link.to.repo/my_repo HEAD:refs/for/master%message=bla%5Fbla
```

More info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_options) (in the "Message" item)

I think you can't use "_" in Gerrit 2.14 (See the "Message" item in 2.14 documentation [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/stable-2.14/Documentation/user-upload.txt)).

Comment: nope...
Uploaded patch set 31: Patch Set 30 was rebased.
bla%5Fbla

Comment: @EyalWurmbrand One workaround is to use `ssh -p 29418 $username@$gerrithost gerrit review $commit -m "bla_bla"`.